# Remove data after certain date in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have data with this shape :

```
date (index)         | x | y
2015-01-01 12:05    | 0 | 10
2015-01-01 12:10    | 0 | 3.6
2015-01-01 12:15    | 1 | 10.2
2015-01-01 12:20    | 0 | 2.8
2015-01-01 12:25    | 1 | 3.6
2015-01-01 12:30    | 5 | 4.8
2015-01-01 12:35    | 2 | 8.9
2015-01-01 12:40    | 7 | 11.9
2015-01-01 12:45    | 1 | 11.8
2015-01-01 12:50    | 0 | 12.0
2015-01-01 12:55    | 2 | 10.9
```

Goal is to remove all the data when y < 5 (standby) but also remove the data 15mn after standby (range of data when y < 5).
At the end, I will have that :

```
date (index)        | x | y
2015-01-01 12:05    | 0 | 10
2015-01-01 12:50    | 0 | 12.0
2015-01-01 12:55    | 2 | 10.9
```

How to do that ?
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by *stanby*, could you plz explain in details?

Comment: Standby is a range of data when y < 5. We have standby 2015-01-01 12:10, and between 2015-01-01 12:20 - 2015-01-01 12:30

Comment: Why does the value `2015-01-01 12:15    | 1 | 10.2` is excluded from output?
`

Comment: because I remove data y < 5 and all the data 15mn after 2015-01-01 12:10

Answer (score 0):

The lazy way?

convert each line to a string. Then check if the int(line[27]) < 5 and line[28] == ".".